# let $a$ and $b$ are both integers. Is it correct to consider cases, for instance, let $a = 2k$ and $b= 2m$. Then consider $a$ be even and $b$ be odd?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

\begin{equation}
\text { If } a b=4, \text { then }(a-b)^{3}-9(a-b)=0
\end{equation}

Comment: I think what you want to know isn't really clear.

Comment: I would like to prove the implication...

Comment: And regarding your first question, I think, if $m$ is not an integer, then $b$ might be odd .. for instance $$3 = 2 * \frac{3}{2}$$

Comment: Take $a=4$, and $b=1$ i.e., $k=2$ and $m=\frac{1}{2}$, then $ab=4$ and $(a-b)^3-9(a-b)=(4-1)^3-9(4-1)=27-27=0$

Comment: Yes,  you may take the cases you have mentioned,

Comment: I do not think it is correct to prove a question like this with examples...

Comment: So, you want a generalized proof? Then you have to make sure the statement is vaild for all integers first, then you can start. @AvinashMaharaj

Comment: well the question started by saying let a and b, be integers... sorry if i phrased the question poorly.

Comment: $\text { If } a b=4, \text { then }(a-b)^{3}-9(a-b)=0$
proof:
 Here are the possible a,b pair: $(2,2),(-2,-2),(1,4),(-1,-4),(4,1),(-4,-1)$. In all of them, the equation holds

Comment: @AvinashMaharaj I think you should add this in your main text.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It's quite alright to sub-divide any Q into cases. We can also  divide it into cases in a different way by observing that $$(a-b)^3-9(a-b)\iff ((a-b=0)\lor ((a-b)^2=9)\iff (a=b\lor |a-b|=3).$$

BTW. The famous Four Color Theorem was only proved in the latter 20th century by  a reduction to an extremely large number of specific cases, which could only be checked by computer. (The print-out of the results was 25,000 pages). So don't be shy about it.

Answer (score 1):

It is a valid approach.

Note that there are two more cases to consider:

1. $a$ is odd and $b$ is even
2. $a,b$ are both odd.

Case 2 is not possible since $ab=4$.

Case 1 is not needed because the equations are symmetric in $a,b$. Hence you can say WLOG (without loss of generality), let $a$ be even and $b$ be odd.

Answer (score 0):

Just Expand.

$$(a - b)^3 - 9(a - b)$$

$$=(a - b)\{(a-b)^2 - 9\}$$

$$=(a - b)(a^2 -2ab + b^2  - 9)$$

$$=(a - b)(a^2 - 8 + b^2 - 9) [\text{as } ab = 4]$$

$$= (a - b)(a^2 + b^2 - 17)$$

So, for the whole expression to be zero,

Either, $a - b = 0 \implies a = b$,

Or, $a^2 + b^2 - 17 = 0 \implies a^2 + b^2 = 17$.

So, The two cases are separate, two of them can't happen simultaneously. [You can't just substitute $a = b$ in the $2$nd eqn. to get an answer] So, *trial and error* is our only option.

You have $ab = 4$, where $a,b \in \Bbb{Z}$.

Possible pairs for $a$ and $b$ $= \{(1,4), (4,1), (2,2), (-1, -4), (-4, -1), (-2, -2) \}$.

Good luck.